# Preventing reverse images search for images on our website

Tags: google-search, google-image-search

I am conducting an online test for few schools. The test will have images and questions based on that. The images are taken from websites like wiki, etc.

Is there a way where I can make the images unsearchable on Google? I have read over it and the internet suggests that I edit the image, flip it, or things like that.  Those are not possible in my case because there is text on few images.

Comment: If you want images that can't be searched, you need to make them yourself. Anything that you found on the web, your students will also be able to find.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

- Adding *heavy* [watermarks](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/36761/7253)
- Modifying size, orientation and color of the [original image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/58401/7253)

Anyway, there is no a detailed step by step process to achieve this, you will end up modifying and testing the image if it is being recognized by Google reverse image search.

Answer (score 0):

This may be as simple as placing the images you do not want indexed within an image directory you can exclude. For example, within a directory such as /noindex-images. Within you robots.txt file, you can then add,

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /noindex-images/
```

Of course, your `<img>` tags would have to modified to point to the images within /noindex-images.

Comment: That wouldn't help if they were already indexed elsewhere.   I think the question is about using images and preventing people from being able to find the original source of the image.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The images would disappear from the index if they do not exist as they are linked now. It would be just a matter of time. As far as the question of the image being found at the original source, I do not see it in the question. However, I do understand how you get that. If the OP does not a copyright license for the image, then they cannot use it. Wikipedia uses CC at least so that should be okay. If the OP is looking to modify the image to avoid detection, that would be more work than I would recommend. If the OP represents an educational organization then fair use applies.

Comment: It sounds to me like they don't want it to be found because it would give students a way to get the answers to the test questions easily as opposed to being for copyright reasons.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Ah Ha! Interesting point!! I never thought of that. BTW- I never cheated in school. Never really needed to so it never occurred to me that a student would try and find the image. If that is the case, then a simple script that renders the image could potentially make it harder. Even with modification, I suspect it can still be found. Perhaps rendering the image 180 degrees and then using a transform: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp or even base64 encoding. Who knows?? Cheers!!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, That was one of the goals.